# Xcode custom header template: ___DATE___ format

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, gcc, macros

As in title, I just want set a custom format for macro ___DATE___ : is it possibile?

Default format is **mm/dd/yy**, but I would like to have **yyyy-mm-dd**

Also, I can't find official documentation for all available macros.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The format for the `___DATE___` parameter can be set in Settings.app.

Settings.app -> Language & Region -> Advanced -> Dates

Then set the **Short** format to be how you want it to appear.

Answer (score 1):

The `__DATE__` macro is part of the C++ standard, and the format is specified precisely by that standard (as `Mmm dd yyyy`, not `mm/dd/yy`). That is what I'd expect XCode to produce for an Objective-C program; I know nothing about Swift.

You can find a list of macros defined by GCC in [the Gnu CPP documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Predefined-Macros.html#Predefined-Macros). I believe Clang (used by default by XCode) implements the same ones.